gradle error: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'
am a react native developper and i recently started my journey to learn flutter and uppon running flutter run command am having this error
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Floidus\Desktop\AwesomeProject\android\app\build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> org/bouncycastle/operator/OperatorCreationException

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 17s
5 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 4 up-to-date

at first i thought it's related to flutter, then i tried to build an app in react native with gradle i got the same problem, how ever getting the same code into another machine it worked,
i searched all over the web i didnt get any result, can anyone give me a hand in that

Make sure you are using correct version of Gradle.
You can check it in build.gradle dependencies located at /android/build.gradle
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:x.x.x' // <-put right version here
}

For start you can try with latest version, which you can check here
